# No sound, no shutdown Xubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: sound, xubuntu, shutdown

I have an old laptop (Toshiba satellite a100).

I installed Xubuntu 10.04 on it, sound worked, PC was shutting down properly.

However, I could not install some programs I wanted (WPS office) because of outdated libraries.

I decided to install Xubuntu 14.04.2.

It works smoothly, but there is no sound and the computer will not shutdown by itself. 
Shutting it down from terminal does not work eiher.

I would like to know if it is possible to get the older libraries/drivers that are responsible for shutdown from xubuntu 10.04 and 'put them' into ubuntu 14.04.2.

Can some one point me in the right direction?

Thank you,

Andrey

Comment: what is the output from `sudo poweroff`? that will help

Comment: did you get any errors while trying to shutdown ?

Comment: Hi,thank you for asking... In fact the output is:

Comment: Hi,thank you for asking... In fact the output is:          Broadcast message from andrew@andrew-Satellite-A100     (/dev/pts/0) at 23:38 ...                                       The system is going down for power off NOW!                                                              afterwards, the screen switches to the shutdown image (with the little wheel turning) Then the wheel freezes and the computer just stays like that.